Line ending differences in scripts generated by .NET 4.8 WinForms and .NET 6 API projects
I have two projects with the following structure:
WinForms Project (using .NET 4.8):
This project has a UI Layer, App Layer, and Agent Layer.
The UI sends user selections to the App Layer, which forwards requests to the Agent Layer.
The Agent Layer generates a long SQL script that is consumed by other teams in their projects.
This project works correctly, and I cannot make any changes to it.
API Project (using .NET 6):
User selections are sent to an API endpoint.
The API references the App Layer service of the WinForms project as a service reference (e.g., wsappClient).
The same service used by the WinForms UI is called in the API to generate the script.
The Problem
The scripts generated by the WinForms UI and the API differ in line-ending characters:
WinForms UI Script: Uses \r\n (Windows line endings).
API Script: Uses \n (Unix line endings).
This inconsistency causes issues when other teams use these scripts in their projects, especially since they rely on substring operations (e.g., extracting characters 3 to 7).
These substring-based operations are widely used across the company and cannot be easily changed.
Additionally, the script generated by the WinForms UI sometimes contains intentional \n characters within specific sections.
As a result, applying normalization (e.g., replacing \n with \r\n globally) is not an option because it could alter the intended behavior of these specific parts of the script.
Users have reported errors when normalization was attempted.
Debugging Observations
When I inspect the response from the service in both the WinForms and API projects, the line endings differ.
The WinForms UI correctly handles both \r\n and \n where appropriate.
Constraints
I cannot modify the WinForms project (it works correctly as is).
Both projects run on Windows servers.
The solution must be implemented in the API layer.
Script Generated by the WinForms UI
{
  "script": "Line 1\r\nLine 2\nLine 3\r\n"
}

Script Generated by the API
{
  "script": "Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3\n"
}

How can I ensure that the scripts generated by the API have consistent line endings (\r\n for most cases) while preserving the intentional \n characters within specific sections of the script?
Thank you in advance for your suggestions!
